# nodejs with pm2 use process mode

Tags: node.js, pm2

I can't find the usage on `pm2` github document, How to use --harmony and process arg ?

```
node --harmony app.js staging

pm2 start app.js --node-args="--harmony-generators"  ??
```

Comment: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/#enabling-harmony-es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare JSON configuration processes.json:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    // Application #1
    "name"        : "worker-app",
    "script"      : "worker.js",
    "args"        : ["--toto=heya coco", "-d", "1"],
    "watch"       : true,
    "node_args"   : "--harmony",
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/this/is/a/path/to/start/script",
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN": "xxx"
    }
  },{
    // Application #2
    "name"       : "api-app",
    "script"     : "api.js",
    "instances"  : 4,
    "exec_mode"  : "cluster_mode",
    "error_file" : "./examples/child-err.log",
    "out_file"   : "./examples/child-out.log",
    "pid_file"   : "./examples/child.pid"
  }]
}
```

Then you can run:

```
$ pm2 start processes.json
```